# How to fix automatic typeConversion with useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using react `useState` hooks to handle a simple form submission with a user Object which contains non string value. 
When I use the spread operator to set a new state with setUser my boolean value are directly converted as string.

```
      name: '',
      isMinor: false
  })
```

Here my inital user, when I use setUser to update it, `isMinor` is converted to "false" or "true".

```
const handleUser = ({target}) => {
    const name = target.name;
    setUser({
        ...user,
        [name]: target.value
    });
};
```

Here is a simple example which describe my problem :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nt9up5

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that `target.value` comes from the DOM, and the DOM doesn't store booleans for radio input values, only strings.

So it's not related to the use of the spread operator, it's a string right from the beginning.

And even though it's rendered with React, the source of the data is still a raw DOM event, so there's nothing React can do about that.

One way to fix it could be to do something like this:

```
setUser({
    ...user,
    [name]: target.value === "true"
});
```

Comment: And is it the same with numbers ?
I  also have a select with options and I want to save an array's keys as value.
Do you have a workaround for big forms with booleans, number and string or do I have to switch in `setUser` depending on the element being modified.

Comment: Same with numbers - all input values are strings. Even an `<input type="number">` returns a string. There might be exceptions here that I'm not aware of, but generally, the DOM will give you strings for input values.